# HTML table column re-sizing on React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a HTML table inside my react application. Now I have a requirement to resize my table columns by raging on the column header. Found lots of react solutions by searching on the web but almost all of them are with a table component(Ex. React Table, RC Table, React Grid).

I am looking for a pure react solution to integrate with my existing Table. Found lots of jQuery libraries but it is not recommending to use jQuery with react.
If I go for a pure java script solution will it create a conflict with the actual DOM and React DOM since pure java script directly changing the actual DOM?

Anyone have a working sample with react or any recommended way to go ahead?

Comment: If you need resizing, flexbox is a way to go.

Comment: Is flexbox supporting for dynamic resizing? I need to resising by dragging on column

Comment: Yes, main advantage of using flexbox is that it supports dynamic resizing of flex items.